# Ionic/Cordova Mac iOS platform Add - TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) at macosRelease

Tags: xcode, macos, cordova, ionic-framework, macos-ventura

Error comes when I try to add iOS platform using ionic cordova platform add iOS.

Current error is node_modules/macos-release/index.js:30
const [name, version] = kshfNameMap.get(release);
^

TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
at macosRelease

Expected : iOS platform must be added successfully

Answer (score 2):

The error comes for macOS Ventura, because in node_modules > mac_os_release > index.js
in nameMap Map , there is no entry for Ventura.

Until next release of this library we have to fix it manually.
Just check version of your macOS and add the following entry in nameMap object on the top.

```
[22, ['Ventura','13.2']]
```

Note: my macOS version is 13.2

Changes in index.js [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spiTi.png)
How to check my macOS version[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KKoN.png)

Enjoy:)

Comment: After you change it in your node-modules, you can create a patch with npm patch package, so that you don't have to do it everytime you reinstall your node modules: https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

Comment: Absolutely correct. Thanks @Mister_CK